# if else statement for copy/ pasting key values

Tags: vba, excel

i have a code piece from my working code which copies and pastes datas from other Worksheets to one masterworkbooks mastersheet. The code below lets me copy and paste datas from column BX to column A's first empty row and does the same for column CC to column B's first empty row. I would however like to paste the column CC to Column B's (10th) row. How can i do this?

```
 lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 With copySheet.Range("BX2:BX" & lRow)
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
 End With

 'Determine last row of Column B in copySheet
 lRow = copySheet.Cells(copySheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 With copySheet.Range("CC2:CC" & lRow)
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
 End With
```

Now i would like to add an if condition for another column; which should say "if column U in Worksheet "data" has cell value "8636" then these values should be pasted to Column H in Worksheet "KomKo"(pastesheet); to the next row as i used the code above in the "with" part.

Else( If the value in Column H is not 8636) then it should paste the value inside this column to Column G at Worksheet "KomKo"(pastesheet) with same preferences as above again.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if worksheetfunction.CountIf(Column("U"),"8636")>0 then
    *Copy to Column H*
else
    *Copy to Column G*
end if
```